# Swagger Apache CXF JAX-RS Maven

Tags: maven, jax-rs, cxf, swagger

I am having trouble using swagger with Apache CXF, JAX-RS services.

beans.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
<bean id="apiListingResourceJSON" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON"/>
<bean id="apiDeclarationProvider" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider"/>
```

Example use:

```
@Path("/")
@Api(value="/", description="VenturoSoft eMustering Services")
public class Service {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Service.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/echo/{input}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get Ping", response = String.class)
    public String ping(@PathParam("input") String input) {
        return PingImpl.ping(input);
    }
```

Pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Run:

```
mvn tomcat7:run-war
```

But when I load:

```
http://localhost:13000/jaxrs-service/api
```

I get no response.

```
http://localhost:13000/jaxrs-service/echo/echoSomething
```

Works as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at some very old dependencies.  From your code, it looks like you're using JAXRS.  If that's the case, the latest dependencies should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Please follow the JAXRS sample here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/java-jaxrs-cxf

Which should show you how to correctly configure the server.